# Sending custom data in the SignIn with AWS Amplify using CUSTOM_AUTH flow in Android

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I need to send some custom data in the AWS Amplify's SignIn() request while using the CUSTOM_AUTH flow type.

My custom data will the be telling the backend which OTP generation service to use during SignIn (SMS or WhatsApp based OTP).

But the problem is that though I can send the OTP method in the client-metadata But this doesn't get received in the custom auth's lambda triggers because of using CUSTOM_AUTH flow.

Is there any way through which I can send custom data via something like: request headers. If yes, please help how to send that.

Comment: did u find a solution or workaround for this ?

Comment: @iJade No, didn't find.